# Can I use a 1/8 water supply line for a dryer with steam refresh option?

Tags: dryer, gas, steam

I have a whirlpool steam refresh dryer that is not next to the washer or a water pipe. Can I use a 1/8" flexible pipe tapped into a pipe and then increase to fit on the dryer?

Answer (score 1):

In the plumbing world this is fine.  However it might not be fine with your dryer.  You will need to read the manual or call the manufacturer to get an answer.

I don't foresee a dryer using a steaming feature needing more than a 1/8" line but who knows if there is some sort of pressure rating needed.  It is probable that the manufacturer doesn't use 1/8" because it just isn't a commonly used size anymore and you can get screw hoses from big box for larger sizes.